# Outlook Automatic reply 'Out of of Office' rule for same day/time each week

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to set an automatic 'out of office' rule for same day/time each week. I'm trying to combat being invited to meetings when I will be out of the office (not everyone checks availability when scheduling meetings). I've looked a the 'rule' setting function in File > Automatic Replies (Out of Office) and unlike setting 'recurring' calendar meetings where you can select the day and time - this doesn't seem to be a function in auto replies options.

Comment: "set an automatic 'out of office' rule for same day/time each week. I'm trying to combat being invited to meetings when I will be out of the office" - I feel some confusion here. Do you want to sent OOO message when you RECEIVE an invitation during you're not working, or when the meeting is SCHEDULED during your absence?

Comment: scheduled - so that when they are adding me they get a notice I'm not available

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, we could set following rule in outlook to auto-reply the messages received in certain days of the week(such as Friday, Sunday etc.), please check if it could work for you:

[image]

Comment: Don't think this would work as it is to be sent after a prescribed HH:MM rather than a 'day'